# Похожий визуальный редактор (конструктор) только на python

Tags: python, веб-программирование, конструктор, idle

Недавно начала изучать как создавать своих веб пауков, т.к. в программировании новичок, но мне попался инструмент browser automation studio (BAS) bablosoft.com, правда на Javascript.
Интересуют похожие инструменты, как браузерами так и с программированием вообщем связанные

https://bablosoft.com/

Как пишут в описании:
"Это среда блочного программирования эмуляции человека в браузере. В ней можно как просто загружать страницы по запросу, так и создать сложное взаимодействовать с базами данных грузя туда элементы отсортированные по специальному алгоритму. Ещё это openSource проект, и профессионалы могут его поковырять и найти много интересного... "

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень хороший аналог, правда платный [ZennoPoster](https://zennolab.com/ru/products/zennoposter/)